# a password checker with an error i can't find

Tags: python

```
username ="fay"
password ="321"
user_name = input("What is your username?:")
if user_name==username:
    passWord= input("Please enter your password:")
    if passWord == password:
        print("welcome!")
    else:
        password_=("please re-enter password:")
else:
    user_name=("please re-enter username:")
```

#i wanted it to check the username and ask for username again if it's wrong and check password if it's correct and to ask for the password again if it's incorrect`

Comment: also [ask] and [mre]

Comment: This question is confusing.  The title says "error i can't find", implying that there is some actual error here.  What is the error?

Comment: Advice: Don't name your variables `passWord` and `password` because it's confusing.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should to try this:

```
username ="fay"
password ="321"
user_name = input("What is your username?:")
while user_name!=username:
    user_name=input("please re-enter username:")

passWord= input("Please enter your password:")

while passWord != password:
    passWord=input("please re-enter password:")  
 
print("welcome!")
```